# Performing math operations on arrays of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

Creating an eCommerce/financial based application with node I am having trouble working out how to have a base figure in a static var `var budget = 300;` and then have the expenses stored in objects in an array

```
var expenses = [
   {name: "thingy1", price: "40"},
   {name: "thingy2", price: "30"},
   {name: "thingy3", price: "100"}
];
```

and have the prices deducted from the `budget` varible and then displayed in the template

> p.s im using express and swig

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing so I hope this is the answer you want, you may want to consider re-wording it.

```
var budget = 300;
var expenses = [
   {name: "thingy1", price: "40"},
   {name: "thingy2", price: "30"},
   {name: "thingy3", price: "100"}
];
expenses.forEach(function (el) {budget -= el.price;});//Removes the price of each expense from the budget
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted thankyou

Comment: Awesome :D, Can you please accept the answer in that case :)

Comment: the only problem is that it has overriden the budget varible so on the template i wish to display both before and after however this will only display the result

Comment: So in order to achieve that you'll need to create a second variable assign the value of `budget` to it and then loop through the expenses like so:
`var afterExpenses = budget; expenses.forEach(function (el) {afterExpenses -= el.price;});`
 now you'll still have your original `budget` variable along with a new one `afterExpenses` which is the value of the budget minus the expenses.